# Is there a MobilePush extract type?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

According to the Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_use_mobilepush_with_automation_studio.htm&type=0) there is a "MobilePush extract type".

Is this referring to "Mobile Push Detail Extract report" or is there another extract type to pull my MobilePush lists?

Answer (score 0):

MobilePush Detail Extract is what you should be using to pull send/device level data.